# node.js: How to detect duplicate exports with eslint?

Tags: node.js, eslint

Could anyone provide eslintrc rules which detect errors in code below?

```
exports.a = 5;

// something here

exports.a = 10;
```

I tried to use `eslint-plugin-import` with `import/export` rule but it doesn't detect any error in this code

Comment: why are you expecting an error, it's a valid code?

Comment: @Adam
i expect something like this: `Multiple exports of name 'a'`
I tried to use this rule: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/export.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import/export` rule is focused more specifically on ES2016+ `import` and `export` syntax. Commonjs exports is dynamic, sometimes is hard to detect duplicate. The following is hard to check:

```js
// dynamic
var a = 'test';
exports[a] = 1;
exports.test = 1;
// exports with module.exports
exports.a = 1;
module.exports = {
  a: 2
};
```

I wrote a plugin to check the simple duplicate commonjs exports: [eslint-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/d-band/eslint-plugin-commonjs). But I don't recommend to check the commonjs exports.